# microphone distance in spaced omnidirectional field recording

Tags: field-recording, stereo, omni

What is your prefered microphone spacing in AB stereo (spaced omnidirectional microphones) for field recordings, and why?

Comment: I've not used spaced omni in the field, but I could see the spacing varying based on the situation and desired sound.

Answer (score 2):

I think its a matter of personal preference - mine being roughly shoulder-width apart. Since you're experimenting with spaced omni's, be sure to look into the [Jecklin Disk](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jecklin_Disk) technique.